# How to monitor webmethod by using WSO2 BAM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I have integrated WSO2 ESB and BAM. Greatly, I'm able to monitor the Service Proxy. But I wonder if there is anyway to monitor the operator/WebMethod of proxy. 
 Please give me some advice.

I already use Bam mediator to collect ESB data for monitoring Webmethod. But my problem is there is not payload_request_count/response_count... data to sent to bam_service_data_publisher. Whereby the dashboard is always empty.
So how could I do to send those properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the BAM mediator to a sequence (when adding a mediator, choose Agent -> BAM) and specify the BAM server profile and stream you want to use to start capturing and sending data events to the BAM server. Be sure to enable statistics on the sequence to start collecting the data.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/BAM+Mediator

In addition you can use Api Manager to control and monitor your web method.
http://wso2.com/api-management/

Comment: Also you can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator

Comment: Thank you, i add your link.

Comment: Thank Milad, I'm using WSO2 Bam as your suggestion. I installed Service_Statistics_Monitoring, I create bam_service_data_publisher (and version named 2.0) and sent request to Sample Proxy service, and the data already appeared in EVENT_KS. However, when I open the dashboard, I can not see the graphic. The request number of Proxy Service shown here is 0. What am I missing somethings? Please help me, it took me days.